# Please find problem in my html <form> tag

Tags: html, forms, tags

Hi? I'm a university student of Korea,
and this semester I'm studying internet programming.

I made html, and I made tag.
However I think that there is problem in my tag.
In fact I hardly effort to find problem, but I cannot find that.

Experts!!!Please find the problem!!!!
This is my form tag.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="firstForm" action="http://kisschks.hosting.paran.com/noname2.php">
<table width=500 border=1>
<tr>
<td width=100>이름</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" size="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>비밀번호</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" size="20" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>학번</td>
<td><input type="text" name="schoolnum" size="21"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>전화번호</td>
<td><select name="fst">
    <option value="010" selected>010</option>
    <option value="011">011</option>
    <option value="016">016</option>
    <option value="017">017</option>
    <option value="018">018</option>
    <option value="019">019</option>
    </select> - <input name="sec" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4"> - <input name="trd" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>캠퍼스</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="campus" value="명륜">명륜
<input type="radio" name="campus" value="율전" checked>율전
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>학년</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="1학년" checked>1학년
<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2학년">2학년
<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="3학년">3학년
<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="4학년">4학년
<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="휴학">휴학
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>고향</td>
<td><textarea name="고향" rows=3 cols=20>
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>하고픈말</td>
<td><textarea name="intro" rows=3 cols=20></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 align="center">
<input type="button" value="안씁니다" disabled>
<input type="reset" value="다시작성">
<input type="submit" value="등록">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi lyn. what u trying to do with this form? and what is the error message?

Comment: The markup will be much cleaner if you use `<fieldset>` and css instead of a table...

Comment: I want tn make personal homepage.

Comment: You'll need to describe the problem itself. Does it look wrong, behave wrong, not appear at all, ...?

Comment: @LYN: Stop pressing enter in the comments. It submits multiple comments.

Comment: What problem are you having? Better post your php code too

Comment: How is the conclusion wrong? You need to be much clearer in describing it. What are you expected to see, and how is the observed behaviour different from that?

Comment: If I clike the submit button, there should be conclusion. However if I click the submit button, there is no conclusion. My professor said to me that there is a problem in my form tag

Comment: conclusion: my name and my campus etc. The things that I wrote should be seen in my homepage.

Comment: What is there instead of the conclusion? Does it stay on the same page, give you a blank page, a page with the wrong content, an error message? Or does your browser pop up error dialogs, or does your computer shutdown and start to sob? In short, don't tell us what *isn't* happening, tell us what *is* happening.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned your problem exactly but I do find `charset` meta missing for the Korean language you are using on the form:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**Interesting Resources:**

- [What Beautiful HTML Code Looks Like](http://css-tricks.com/what-beautiful-html-code-looks-like/)
- [Fix Your Site With the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)

Comment: what is that? Do I have to download?

Comment: @bemace: That's extremely important link here for sure :)

Comment: @LYN: You need to read those articles on how to make a valid html page.

Comment: @LYN - No, you just go there and put your code in and it looks for errors.  I didn't find anything major in this case, which makes me suspect your PHP code.

Comment: @bemace: Oh I thought OP was talking about links I had posted in my answer.

Comment: @Sarfraz - could have been, it's hard to say

Answer (score 1):

One thing that *might* be relevant is that you haven't specified either `method="POST"` or `method="GET"` in your form tag.  Though if you're using `$_REQUEST` in your php it shouldn't matter either way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't say what your code was doing wrong or what you expected but didn't get... but...

Go to:

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

and paste your code in there. It turns out the `<head>` element cannot be empty. Don't just take my revision below, you really should read the output of the Validator to understand what kind of changes needed to be made in order to achieve valid HTML.

Here is valid code that should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
      hello
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="firstForm" action="http://kisschks.hosting.paran.com/noname2.php">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="100">
            이름
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" type="text" size="15" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            비밀번호
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" size="20" maxlength="15" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            학번
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="schoolnum" size="21" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            전화번호
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="fst">
              <option value="010" selected="selected">
                010
              </option>
              <option value="011">
                011
              </option>
              <option value="016">
                016
              </option>
              <option value="017">
                017
              </option>
              <option value="018">
                018
              </option>
              <option value="019">
                019
              </option>
            </select> - <input name="sec" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />- <input name="trd" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            캠퍼스
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="campus" value="명륜" />명륜 <input type="radio" name="campus" value="율전" checked="checked" />율전
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            학년
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="1학년" checked="checked" />1학년 <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2학년" />2학년 <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="3학년" />3학년 <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="4학년" />4학년 <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="휴학" />휴학
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            고향
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="고향" rows="3" cols="20">
</textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            하고픈말
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="intro" rows="3" cols="20">
</textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="button" value="안씁니다" disabled="disabled" /><input type="reset" value="다시작성" /><input type="submit" value="등록" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <p>
      html form ta
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that in the `<html>` tag, it specifies English as the language. I suspect that is not the correct language, but you can fix that yourself once you get everything else working.

Good luck with your studies.